# getting products from all category levels in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Let say my category level is like:

```
Parent
 - child one
 - child two
   - child two (one)
```

Now I am visiting `Parent` page. but i want to get all products from all levels and not only parent.

## Question

1. How can I have access to products in `parent` `child one` `child
   two` & `child two(one)`?
2. How to show them by pagination in `parent` page?

## Codes

this is what i have currently and it only shows products under `parent`

```
 public function totalcategoriessubs($catslug) {
    $categories = Category::where('slug','=',$catslug)->with('childs')->paginate(12);
    $products = Product::whereHas('category', function($q) use($catslug){
      $q->where('slug',$catslug);
      })->paginate(12);
return view('front.categoriessubs', compact('products', 'categories'));
  }
```

## UPDATE

I have changed my function and added `$category` to it so now is like:

```
public function totalcategoriessubs($catslug) {
    //changed
    $category = Category::where('slug','=',$catslug)->with('childs')->first();

    //testing this
    $products = Product::whereHas('category', function($q) use ($catslug,$category)
    {
      $q->where(function($q) use ($catslug,$category) {
        $q->where('slug',$catslug)->orWhere('category_id',$category->id);
      });
    })->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
    //end testing

return view('front.categoriessubs', compact('products', 'category'));
```

}

with this i can get `product` list of

```
Parent
 - child one
 - child two
```

but still can't get products of `child two (one)`

any idea?

Comment: How deep your category tree goes?

Comment: @vieny I didn't provide limitation for it but maximum i need till `child two (one)` is 2 i think.

Comment: Did you try `->with('childs.childs')`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir no man the part that should be fixed is `$products = Product:......` in this i must include products of `$categories` childs, so it get them all.

Comment: ......any idea?

Comment: You want to find products that are in subcategories of `$category`?

Comment: Yes i want find products in: parent category,child one and child one child. `i want when im visiting parent page see products in all levels.`

Answer (score 0):

```
 Category::with(['childsOne', 'childsTwo' => function($query){
    $query->with('ChildsTwoChilds');
    ])->where('slug', $catSlug)->paginate(12)
```

Comment: no bro you get it wrong, is not about category names is about deep. category names are dynamic could be anything i cannot hard code them.